# Retrieve US patents claims

Tags: claims, uspto, databases

I am trying to automatically retrieve patents claims from different jurisdictions. 
[Open Patent Services](http://ops.epo.org) allows to retrieve patents Claims from WO, EU, and several other patent offices whereas no coverage for US jurisdiction is provided. [USPTO PatentsView](http://www.patentsview.org) supports fetching abstracts from US patents but no Claims. To adhere to Terms of Use of patent search engines, I don't want to use a web crawler. **What patent search engines do allow to automatically retrieve Claims of patents and patent applications from USPTO patent databases (via API)?**

Comment: I don’t know if it does all you want, but you should check out https://www.lens.org/lens/

Comment: Thanks, it is really great tool but it lacks an application programming interface currently.

Comment: I thought they were adding it. The Lens is academic so it might be worth contacting them.

Comment: It doesn't handle claims but [Pair bulk data] (https://pairbulkdata.uspto.gov/)  is the only other patent api I'm aware of not mentioned so far.

Comment: Lacking an api one option would be to download the 10G claims file from patentsview and pull what you want from  it  http://www.patentsview.org/download/ It's not ideal but it might be your only option?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `patent_client`! It's a python module that searches the live USPTO and EPO databases using a Django-style API. The results from any query can then be cast into pandas DataFrames or Series with a simple `.to_pandas()` call.

You can get what you're looking for like this:

```
from patent_client import Inpadoc, Patent, PublishedApplication

# US Documents
Patent.objects.get("<patent_number>").claims_text
PublishedApplication.objects.get("<pub_number>").claims_text

# International / INPADOC documents
Inpadoc.objects.get("<Publication Number>").claims.claims_text
```

There is also a built-in parser for claims that will produce structured data, dividing the claim into limitations and providing dependency information:

```
from patent_client import Inpadoc, Patent, PublishedApplication

# US Documents
Patent.objects.get("<patent_number>").claims_text
PublishedApplication.objects.get("<pub_number>").claims

# International / INPADOC documents
Inpadoc.objects.get("<Publication Number>").claims.claims
```

A great place to start is the [User Guide Introduction](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/)

[image: Patent Client Logo]

[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/parkerhancock/patent_client) | [Docs](https://patent-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

(Full disclosure - I'm the author and maintainer of patent_client)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. This is quite an interesting Python library. You might want to search the Software Recommendation SE site to see if there is a relevant question. This will help get the word out about the library.

Comment: Your logo seems a little large for this site.